# MATLAB Publish enforce newline

Tags: matlab

I want to use MATLAB Publish to document my code.
My question is, how can I enforce a newline, that is not shown when typing `help getImProcessParam` in the command line?

In my m-file I've written

```
%% Get Image Processing Parameter
% This function return a struct containing some settings to process an
% image.
%
% Usage:
% X=getImProcessParam(set)
% input: an identifier to select a parameter set
% output: a struct containing all selectable parameters, some are set so defined values, some keep empty
```

When I type in help `getImProcessParam` to my command line I receive:

```
Get Image Processing Parameter
This function return a struct containing some settings to process an image.
Usage:
X=getImProcessParam(set)
input: an identifier to select a parameter set
output: a struct containing all selectable parameters, some are set so defined values, some remain empty
```

But when I use Publish, the whole comment is pressed into a single line. How can I supress this behavior and what do I have to write to get the same prompt on command line and with Publish?

I.e. `\n` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add and extra space between % and the first character. This will force the publish output to preformatted text.

```
%% Get Image Processing Parameter
% This function return a struct containing some settings to process an image.
%
%  Usage:
%  X=getImProcessParam(set)
%  input: an identifier to select a parameter set
%  output: a struct containing all selectable parameter, some are set so defined values, some keep empty
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that adding the extra space, as previously suggested, changes the formatting to a monospace font. I was able to get a new line by using html markup.

```
%% Get Image Processing Parameter
% This function return a struct containing some settings to process an
% image.
%
% <html>
% <p>Usage:<br>
% X=getImProcessParam(set)<br>
% input: an identifier to select a parameter set<br>
% output: a struct containing all selectable parameters, some are set so defined values, some keep empty</p>
% </html>
```

I think this will only work if you're publishing to in html format. You should be able to do something similar for a Latex document too.